# Anyone know how to convert a little OpenGL code to metal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl, avfoundation, metal

I have been using some OpenGL code for my objective-c camera capture session, which I barely understand. Now OpenGL is depreciated, and I have no idea how to convert this little bit of OpenGL code to metal. If anyone knows both enough to convert the below please help.

```
if (self.eaglContext != [EAGLContext currentContext]) {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.eaglContext];
}
glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

there is a little more OpenGL I didn't see:

```
_eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
_videoPreviewView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds context:_eaglContext];
_videoPreviewView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = NO;
_videoPreviewView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
_videoPreviewView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:_videoPreviewView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_videoPreviewView];
[_videoPreviewView bindDrawable];
_videoPreviewViewBounds = CGRectZero;
_videoPreviewViewBounds.size.width = _videoPreviewView.drawableWidth;
_videoPreviewViewBounds.size.height = _videoPreviewView.drawableHeight;
_ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_eaglContext options:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]} ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a trivial conversion from OpenGL to Metal. The first step would be to replace the `GLKView` with an `MTKView`. You'll want to then  create an `id<MTKViewDelegate>` to handle the actual drawing, resizing, etc. I recommend watching the [Adopting Metal](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/602/) video from WWDC 2016. It shows how to get up and running with an `MTKView`.

To do the blending, you'll need to set the blending options on the `MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachmentDescriptor` that you use to create the render pipeline state. You'll need to set the `blendingEnabled` property to `YES` and set the `rgbBlendOperation` property to `MTLBlendOperationAdd`. Then you'll set the `sourceRGBBlendFactor` to `MTLBlendFactorOne` and the `destinationRGBBlendFactor` to `MTLBlendFactorOneMinusSourceAlpha`.

You can create a `CIContext` from a `id<MTLDevice>` via `+[CIContext contextWithMetalDevice:options:]`

Comment: Could you also have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910290/avaudiosession-plays-sound-on-receiver-or-mic-switches-to-front?noredirect=1#comment98576729_55910290

Comment: Sorry I have never used the AV framework, so don't know anything about that.